# error in process sentinel: Wrong type argument: integer-or-marker-p, nil

Tags: debugging, dired, search, error, find-dired

I get this error when I search dired with `M-x find-name-dired`:

```
error in process sentinel: Wrong type argument: integer-or-marker-p, nil
```

The search finds the files then ends with this error. I'm not sure if the search ends prematurly.

Google search reveals old questions with similer error related to elisp.

What causing this error?

---

Debugger content:

```
Debugger entered--entering a function:
* find-dired-sort-by-filename()
  funcall(find-dired-sort-by-filename)
  (progn (narrow-to-region (point) (- (point-max) 2)) (funcall find-dired-refine-function) (widen))
  (if find-dired-refine-function (progn (narrow-to-region (point) (- (point-max) 2)) (funcall find-dired-refine-function) (widen)))
  (save-restriction (widen) (if find-dired-refine-function (progn (narrow-to-region (point) (- (point-max) 2)) (funcall find-dired-refine-function) (widen))) (let ((point (point-max))) (goto-char point) (insert "\n  find " (substring state 0 -1) " at " (substring (current-time-string) 0 19)) (dired-insert-set-properties point (point))))
  (save-excursion (save-restriction (widen) (if find-dired-refine-function (progn (narrow-to-region (point) (- (point-max) 2)) (funcall find-dired-refine-function) (widen))) (let ((point (point-max))) (goto-char point) (insert "\n  find " (substring state 0 -1) " at " (substring (current-time-string) 0 19)) (dired-insert-set-properties point (point)))) (setq mode-line-process (format ":%s" (process-status proc))) (delete-process proc) (force-mode-line-update))
  (let ((inhibit-read-only t)) (save-excursion (save-restriction (widen) (if find-dired-refine-function (progn (narrow-to-region (point) (- (point-max) 2)) (funcall find-dired-refine-function) (widen))) (let ((point (point-max))) (goto-char point) (insert "\n  find " (substring state 0 -1) " at " (substring (current-time-string) 0 19)) (dired-insert-set-properties point (point)))) (setq mode-line-process (format ":%s" (process-status proc))) (delete-process proc) (force-mode-line-update)))
  (save-current-buffer (set-buffer buf) (let ((inhibit-read-only t)) (save-excursion (save-restriction (widen) (if find-dired-refine-function (progn (narrow-to-region (point) (- ... 2)) (funcall find-dired-refine-function) (widen))) (let ((point (point-max))) (goto-char point) (insert "\n  find " (substring state 0 -1) " at " (substring (current-time-string) 0 19)) (dired-insert-set-properties point (point)))) (setq mode-line-process (format ":%s" (process-status proc))) (delete-process proc) (force-mode-line-update))))
  (if (buffer-name buf) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer buf) (let ((inhibit-read-only t)) (save-excursion (save-restriction (widen) (if find-dired-refine-function (progn (narrow-to-region ... ...) (funcall find-dired-refine-function) (widen))) (let ((point ...)) (goto-char point) (insert "\n  find " (substring state 0 -1) " at " (substring ... 0 19)) (dired-insert-set-properties point (point)))) (setq mode-line-process (format ":%s" (process-status proc))) (delete-process proc) (force-mode-line-update)))) (message "find-dired %s finished." buf))
  (let ((buf (process-buffer proc))) (if (buffer-name buf) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer buf) (let ((inhibit-read-only t)) (save-excursion (save-restriction (widen) (if find-dired-refine-function (progn ... ... ...)) (let (...) (goto-char point) (insert "\n  find " ... " at " ...) (dired-insert-set-properties point ...))) (setq mode-line-process (format ":%s" (process-status proc))) (delete-process proc) (force-mode-line-update)))) (message "find-dired %s finished." buf)))
  find-dired-sentinel(#<process Shell> "exited abnormally with code 1\n")
  recursive-edit()
  debug(error (wrong-type-argument integer-or-marker-p nil))
  buffer-substring-no-properties(nil 245)
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x2c90375830e24c9>)()
  sort-build-lists(forward-line end-of-line #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x2c90375830e24c9>) nil)
  sort-subr(nil forward-line end-of-line #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x2c90375830e24c9>))
  find-dired-sort-by-filename()
  find-dired-sentinel(#<process Shell> "exited abnormally with code 1\n")
```

---

As per @drew's comment I set `(setq debug-on-error t)` and this is the trace I got when I searched with `M-x find-name-dired`:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument integer-or-marker-p nil)
  buffer-substring-no-properties(nil 245)
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x2c90375830e24c9>)()
  sort-build-lists(forward-line end-of-line #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x2c90375830e24c9>) nil)
  sort-subr(nil forward-line end-of-line #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x2c90375830e24c9>))
  find-dired-sort-by-filename()
  find-dired-sentinel(#<process Shell> "exited abnormally with code 1\n")
```

Comment: Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. Also: set `debug-on-error` to `t`, to get a backtrace, and post that as part of your question.

Comment: I added the trace to the question.

Comment: I didn't see the same error starting with `emacs -q`. But in that case it listed a list of files like `find: Desktop: Operation not permitted`. I don't see these not permitted files when I start normally. I don't know if this is relevant.

Comment: The error is caused by `(next-single-property-change (point) 'dired-filename)` returning `nil` because there is no change of text property `dired-filename` in the rest of the accessible buffer section. See the code of [`find-dired-sort-by-filename`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/65f71ca9aaa1587284293e2e34a0e28ee6b42380/lisp/find-dired.el#L429C28-L430C53).

Comment: @Tobias I don't understand the elisp code, is there a solution? The error started to appear recently.

Comment: Dunno, but the error message you show for `emacs -q` makes me think maybe the `find` command you're picking up is the MS Windows `find` command (?). If so, test with `emacs -Q` but load whatever code you normally use (e.g. Cygwin or whatever), to get a GNU/Linux or Unix `find` command.

Comment: Load the **source**-code file (`*.el`) that defines `find-dired-sort-by-filename`, using `M-x load-library`, then reproduce the backtrace and show that better backtrace.

Comment: @Drew Sorry, I could not load `*.el`. I tried `M-x load-library RETURN *.el` but this gives this error `load-library: Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, (*.el)`

Comment: @Drew Here https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Libraries.html#:~:text=To%20load%20an%20Emacs%20Lisp,from%20an%20existing%20Emacs%20buffer. I read that "The M-x load-library command prompts for a library name rather than a file name". What is the name of the library I need to load?

Comment: To load the source code, provide the full name of the EL file, whatever it is, e.g. `foobar.el`. If you don't include the `.el` then a byte-compiled file (`.elc`) will be loaded, which won't improve the backtrace info.

Comment: @Drew I searched for files with `.el` extension and there are hundrdes of them. How do I know which one to load? I also searched for files containing `find-dired-sort-by-filename` there was only one return `Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/History` which seems to be my google history

Comment: `C-h f find-dired-sort-by-filename` tells you what library it's in (`find-dired.el`), and it even gives you a link to the function's definition in that file.

Comment: @Drew Ok. I loaded the library `find-dired.el` but now I don't get the backtrace anymore, I just get the error `Wrong type argument: integer-or-marker-p, nil` I have this on my `.emacs` file: `(setq debug-on-error t)`

Comment: Maybe try setting `debug-ignored-errors` to `nil` - see [Error Debugging](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Error-Debugging.html). Otherwise, `M-x debug-on-entry find-dired-sort-by-filename` and step through the debugger...

Comment: @Drew Ok, I tried `M-x debug-on-entry find-dired-sort-by-filename` and I ran the search. I pasted the debugger content to the question. Does it make sense?

Comment: I think you misunderstood. The reason to use `debug-on-entry` is that it stops as soon as the function is called, rather than when the function generates an error. You can then use the debugger as a tool, stepping through the code and learning what it does as you go. By the time you get to the error, you should have a good idea of what went wrong, or at least the information necessary to deduce what went wrong. Merely posting the stack at the start of the function is useless. The stack from `debug-on-error`, which is actually at the point where the error was generated, is much more useful.

Comment: In any case, Tobias already gave you the cause of the error: it couldn’t find a text property in the buffer. That text property is a way for dired to avoid reparsing the buffer contents every time you interact with it. If the property is missing, then perhaps the buffer does not contain a list of files at all. In your own first comment, you say that you see an error message (“find: Desktop: Operation not permitted”) instead of a list of files when you enter dired. Are you on OSX? Have you given Emacs permission to read private files on all disks? Unless you do, you can expect plenty of errors.

Comment: @db48x Yes. I'am on OSX. How do I give emacs permission to read private files?

Comment: @db48x If so, you are right. I don't know how to use the debugger in this case. Can you explain what I need to do?

Comment: You need do nothing. You already have the back trace from the point of the error, which has most of the information needed. Consult your operating system’s documentation for information about permissions; I don’t use OSX so I cannot really help you there.